# Is there a way to possibly attach a document(from the library) to an email directly?

Tags: 2010, email

Is there a way to possibly attach a document(from the library) to an email directly? Rather than "Email the link"  ? In the case where the person has no access to the library(where the document is located)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the document and choose the option to share it with the person you intend to. In this way he will be able to see the file. There is no way to attach it to the email directly. You can either save the document to your local machine and attach or send the link to the user and at the document properties you make sure to share the document with that person as a guest link.

[Share a document by sending or posting an anonymous guest link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not provide any specific action to send email with attachment...the workaround is to embed the document link into the email body and send the email.

please refer this link.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/204397.aspx

Thanks.